# HTML Textarea with specific line colors

Tags: html, colors, textarea

I've got a `<textarea>`, but I need to color specific lines different colors. Apparently, I can't do this.

I could perhaps use a `<div>`, but I like the look and scrollbar of a `<textarea>`.

Is there any sort of database of HTML elements somewhere that I can check? It's rather annoying having to burden the posters of StackOverflow whenever I can't place the name of an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textareas can only contain plain text. No possibility to format via CSS. You need something like a WYSIWYG Editor (CKEditor or TinyMCE)

Or if readonly, filled by javascript:
Use a simple div which can contain HTML markup inside for your line colors. Then style it with CSS to look like a textarea (scrollbar maybe)

Comment: Problem is, my Javascript is going to be the only thing writing to it, and the `<textarea>` will be read only.

Comment: Then why don't use a simple div which can contain HTML markup inside for your line colors. Then style it with CSS to look like a textarea (scrollbar maybe)

Comment: I suppose I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Got it working. If you add the "div" bit to your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What do you mean with: If you add the "div" bit to your answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Right now your answer only suggests a WYSIWYG editor, but if you have 
"Then why don't use a simple div which can contain HTML markup inside for your line colors" then I'll accept it